# Connect website to MySQL database in cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel

I have uploaded my website in cPanel but still don't know how to change my `.env` file or `database.php` to connect my site to the database. The connection works on localhost without any error but what do I need to change in these file when I move my project from localhost to an online host?

I created my database in `cPanel -> phpmyadmin` and created a user which has a password, my user is a Privileged Users for this database.

How can I connect my project on the host with my database?

My `.env` file looks as follows:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://domain_name

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: which php framework are you using, depend on that file name and location.Please share framework name.

Comment: Laravel framework

Comment: dear please make changes in .env file. it would be hidden.

Comment: I know where must i change(env or config/database.php), but the problem is how should i change it

Comment: Did you import the database to the same cPanel server? If so, you can still use `localhost` as database host.

Comment: I have included my env code. Can you explain what exactly must I do?

Comment: have you imported database from local to cpanel .after that open file manager in cpanel , go to website document root , find for .env and edit this file.

Comment: Yes i did all these. I have edited database name,username,password and i tried with localhost and online host IP both but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have the correct `.env` values (please check this once more to be 100% sure).
If it is the case that you have the correct `.env` values your problem is probably with caching.

Laravel caches config values using `php artisan config:cache` whenever you make a change to your `.env` file you will need to recreate your config cache.
If you cannot run commands on your server you can delete the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file to remove the config cache.

On another note, if your webserver and sqlserver are on the same physical server you can use `localhost` as the correct host.

Comment: Thank you , my problem solved. I have used host IP instead of localhost and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql of **same cpanel or same server** where you have hosted the files, you can use **localhost** in host name, this will work for you.

Comment: Hello @Niranjan Kapadiya, thank you for your contribution, however as you can see in the question OP already tried to use `localhost` as the `DB_HOST`.